# Disable wake up from *all* mice (Windows)?

Tags: windows, mouse, sleep

I know how to disable it for a single mouse. The problem is that I have to do that each time for each mouse and for each USB port. That is, if I disable it for a mouse, and plug it into another USB port, I have to disable it again.

Is it possible to disable wake from **all** mice, no matter which the USB port it is plugged into or what mouse it is?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to have been answered in another [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/631637/how-to-disallow-usb-devices-to-wake-the-computer-by-default-in-windows-7)

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('powercfg -devicequery wake_armed') do powercfg -devicedisablewake "%%A"
```

This needs to be run as an administrator.

To provide a more complete solution here is a script that requests administrator privileges before running the above loop. The admin rights are requested using a Microsoft powertoy (written in VisualBasic, unsurprisingly)

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" (
  elevate %0 do
) else if "%~1"=="do" (
  for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('powercfg -devicequery wake_armed') do (
    if not "%%A"=="NONE" (
      echo Disabling %%A
      powercfg -devicedisablewake "%%A"
    )
  )
  echo All done.
  pause
) else (
  echo Usage: %~nx0
)
```

Comment: Though that certainly “does the job”, I see several shortcomings: It disables all wake sources; It does not deal with newly added devices

Comment: You can launch the script every time you connect a USB device