# How to prevent "Allow this device to wake the computer" from resetting itself when a device is plugged back in

Tags: windows-10, usb, wake-up

Extremely similar problem as the linked post below, but for windows 10.  There isn't a solution for windows 7, but I'm hoping windows 10 has something I can use to permanently disable the ability for a device to wake anything up.

[Similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/631637/how-to-disallow-usb-devices-to-wake-the-computer-by-default-in-windows-7)

More specifically, My xbox controller wakes up my monitors within a minute of them turning off unless I disable it here:
[image: Allow this device to wake the computer]

Once disabled, the monitors stop turning themselves back on, but it's a temporary fix.  If I unplug the controller and plug it back in, the setting is reset to allowing the controller to wake the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: You could make a [.bat file to reset the controller status](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/63148-allow-prevent-devices-wake-computer-windows-10-a.html) each time.

- In a CMD prompt, enter `powercfg -devicequery wake_from_any` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Note the controller's ID, e.g. "HIDCompliantMouse"
- Create the .bat file: `powercfg -devicedisablewake "TheDeviceIDAbove"`.
- Call the .bat file after plugging in the controller.

Alternative: If you can find [the Registry key for the controller's Wake setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2740020/information-about-power-management-setting-on-a-network-adapter), you could change the ownership of the key to TrustedInstaller and the System should be unable to modify that setting. One way to find that setting on your machine is with NirSoft's [RegistryChgangesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html). Export the Registry, change only the Wake setting, export again and use the NirSoft utility to find the key. **N.B.** Making this Registry change may produce undesirable consequences, and the setting may be lost after Windows Update.