# Mouse and Keyboard don't work with Asus z87 motherboard

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard, motherboard, mouse

I just set up a new desktop computer. I am running an Asus Z87 style motherboard. It supports USB 3.0. After installing windows, I started installing some of the drivers from the Asus Z87 drivers disk. I went to install the USB 3.0 drivers thinking it was for USB acceleration or something. I must have not been paying attention and accidentally uninstalled them.

Anyway, after rebooting, I get the mouse and keyboard to work if I am in the BIOS screen, but not at the windows login screen. The keyboard will not type and the mouse will not move. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

The specific ASUS Motherboard is: Z87-A

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem with Z87-A install on Samsung 840 SSD. Installation went well with mouse plugged in to front USB2 port, but mouse disappeared when I installed the Intel USB3 drivers from M/B driver disk. It worked OK in BIOS screens, but not when W7 booted up. I used Samsung utility to format the ssd which was hooked up to another W7 PC, then reinstalled W7 but no Intel drivers.
So far all's well, but USB3 ports probably aren't working properly...
As far as I can ascertain, the Intel drivers are causing the problem, and I'm hoping to find alternatives.
Hope this is sheds a bit of light for you.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to see I am not the only person having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Plug the keyboard and mouse into regular USB ports, not the USB 3 ports

Answer (score 0):

As long as the computer is connected to the internet, if you re-insert the keyboard and mouse, Windows should automatically install the necessary drivers.

Also, to rule out USB 3.0 as an issue, I would try plugging them into standard USB 2.0 ports. USB 3.0 is not necessary for keyboards and mice. You will want to use this for USB 3.0 compatible devices. You can usually use USB 2.0 devices on USB 3.0 ports, but it is unnecessary, unless you have ran out of standard USB 2.0 ports. Mice and keyboards can easily operate at their full potential running through a USB 2.0 ports.

This section is probably not the issue since you notice that they do work while in BIOS, but if you still do not have any progress getting the keyboard and mouse to work, ensure they will work on another computer, if available. If another one isn't available and this is a wireless keyboard and mouse, change the batteries.

What changes did you make in BIOS if any, just to ensure that nothing important changed that could cause issues?

What type of keyboard and mouse do you have just to ensure they aren't a factor?

Comment: They are not wireless. They worked before I ran the USB 3.0 driver installation and they do work on another computer.

Comment: Keyboard is a Generic Microsoft Keyboard.
Mouse is a Razor Death Adder 2013.

Comment: I made sure to set the BIOS settings to default after it stopped working just in case that was a factor. It did not seem to help.

Comment: Did you try using the USB 2.0 ports?

Comment: I did, it did not seem to help. I did find out the top two ports on the back of the motherboard are USB 2.0 They still did not work after being plugged into those.

Comment: Do you have a PS2 keyboard and/or mouse? If so, plug that in the PS2 port and see if it functions.

Comment: Sadly I do not.

Comment: Do your computer speakers make the acknowledgment noise that you plug or unplug the keyboard and/or mouse?

Comment: No, but it would not be a good indication as I also do not get the Windows start up music when the computer boots to windows.

Comment: I am trying a fresh install of Windows 7 to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: How did re-installing the operating system work out for you?

Comment: It fixed it. I haven't tried reinstalling the drivers yet, but I am not running any USB 3.0 devices anyway, so until I do, I won't worry about it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but by chance I found a workaround:

1. Power on your PC, Start Windows 7 (the mouse will not function)
2. plug your USB device (mouse) into a USB 3.0 port when Windows login screen appears
3. Press the shutdown button and wait for the system to shutdown.
4. Replug your device mouse for USB 2.0 port, and power on your PC. Your mouse should function correctly.

It is strange, but it's real! For the time being, always plug the mouse into a USB 3.0 port before a system shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Phuuu here's what worked for me.

After computer reset I got the screen where you can select to enter into windows normally or into safe mode. I selected safe mode and there the usb and mouse was working.

I then uninstalled the crappy intel usb 3 drivers and rebooted and now the mouse and keyboard is working in normal mode again.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem today, but with Windows 10, after updating the BIOS.

The solution has been "disabling" the Intel xHCI Mode in the BIOS (F2 to enter the BIOS -> Advanced Mode -> Advanced).

After that, reboot the PC and you will have the keyboard and the mouse in your Window.

For more information about xHCI you can see this [post](https://superuser.com/a/892726/648123).

The BIOS manual is [here](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/Z87-PRO/E7832_Z87-PRO.pdf).