# USB doesn't work but drivers and device manager seems ok

Tags: laptop, usb, windows-8.1, usb-3, asus-laptop

I have Asus laptop N76V series with Windows 8.1. When it was given to me at work, it had 3 devices with yellow bangs in Device Manager (Error code 32): USB Controller, Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1E26 and - 1E2D.

I cleared all .inf with their vendor ids and device ids and reinstalled drivers.  Intel chipset INF renamed controller to "Intel(R) Series/C216 Chipset Family Universal Serial Bus (USB) Controller - 1E31" and transfered it under “System Devices”. Yellow bangs are dissapeared but USB devices not recognized anyway (I tried mouse and few flash drives). But USB ports are powered – USB LED lamp is turned on.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by turning off xHCI in BIOS:

**XHCI Mode = Disabled**

Perhaps I lose USB 3.0 speed for external hard drives and flash drives.

Comment: This might explain why that fix works>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/480045/what-does-the-bios-setting-xhci-pre-boot-mode-do