# Is there a reason why so many computer cases have only a single USB 3 port?

Tags: usb, case

USB 3 comes in headers that are wired for 2 separate USB 3 ports on 1 header, yet it seems to be quite common to see cases, even mid and full tower cases, to see only 1 USB 3 port on the front, with 2 or even worse 3 USB 2 ports. Why is this so common? It seems like common sense to put them in multiples of 2 (so as not to waste half the header), so is there a good reason why so many cases only have 1 port, or is just a case of extreme cost cutting or "form over function"?

Comment: Related: [*Why do modern computer cases still have USB 2.0 ports?*](https://superuser.com/q/1112714/432690)